# Capture Card capabilities in PayPal Payments Pro

Tags: paypal

Capture Card as I understand it allows a seller to securely accept an online order with credit card name, number and code via a shopping cart. We can subsequently ship the order, add the freight to the invoice and submit the total amount to the credit card for payment. After the payment has been posted the credit card information is wiped from the order.

I was led to believe that I could do this with a PayPal Payments Pro account, so I created one and sent a test invoice through with my own credit card. The amount of the invoice with tax was immediately posted to my PayPal account without the opportunity to add freight.

Can anyone on this forum provide a solution or workaround?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you processing this initially as a sale or an authorization.  If you are wanting to use the DoDirectPayment API with Website Payments Pro, you could process a 1.00 authorization to validate the card.  Then perform all of the calculations that you are needing to, and then process the payment using the DoReferenceTransaction API call where you send across the full amount you want to charge to the buyers card.  You only have to reference the transaction id for the last successful 1.00 auth you did, and PayPal will use the same credit card information.  Otherwise you could also process the DoDirectPayment API call with the full amount at the time of checkout, and just use the DoReferenceTransactions API call to charge any additional charges to where not initially charged such as tax and shipping.

Another option would be to use Express Checkout, and process the transaction as an order.  This will allow you to make more then one authorization/capture against the order.  You can also set a max amount in the Express Checkout API calls.

Comment: Hey Chad! Thanks for the positive reply. I will proceed with your suggestions. Thanks again! Scott